# Casting generic type in linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, casting

So I have class which accepts a generic type parameter and does a little special handling if the type parameter is a subclass of a given type.

```
IEnumerable<T> models = ...

// Special handling of MySpecialModel
if (filterString != null && typeof(MySpecialModel).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
{
    var filters = filterString.Split(...);
    models = 
        from m in models.Cast<MySpecialModel>()
        where (from t in m.Tags
               from f in filters 
               where t.IndexOf(f, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
               select t)
              .Any()
        select (T)m;
}
```

But I'm getting an exception on the last line

```
Cannot convert type 'MySpecialModel' to 'T'
```

If I change the code to use `as` instead of casting, I get this error.

```
The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint.
```

What am I missing here?

**Update**

This class needs can take any type parameter, including `struct`s and built-in types, so a generic constraint would not be a suitable solution in my case.

Comment: did you set the constraint `where T : class` in your generic class?

Comment: @danradu No, but that wouldn't work in my case as the generic class can accept both reference and value type parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Do `Select(x => (MySpecialModel)x)`</strike>

The LINQ `Cast<T>` method will only work for casting elements to that the element already is (such as a base type, derived type, or interface).  It is not intended to cast objects that are able to be cast to a target type. (e.g. `new List<int>{1,2,3}.Cast<long>()` will throw an exception as well.

The above answer wasn't wrong, but it doesn't address the question.

Just because you have proved with reflection that a generic parameter is bound to a given type, doesn't mean that the compiler knows that it is.  In order to make this work, you will need to cast your `T` instance to a common type (e.g. `object`), then cast it to the specific type.  e.g. (changing the last line in your query to `select (T)(object)m` should do the trick.

Comment: Tried `Select(x => (T)x)`. same result

Comment: ohh my bad, change your last line `select (T)(object)m`) - I didn't read the question entirely before answering

Comment: Thanks. The double-cast works, but looks strange. I eventually ended up going with `.Cast<T>()` (which is equivalent and is more aesthetic). If you know of any reason the double-cast would be better, please let me know.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that having the concrete type in the query communicates more to other people who are reading the code (e.g.  it is a `MySpecialModel`, not anything...  It's honestly not clear to me why you are using a generic parameter in the first place, but if the functionality is truly generic, then you should probably refactor out the reflection check anyway .  I really don't have enough context to give you more concrete advice...

Comment: I agree with your point on redesigning this method to remove reflection. In fact, this whole class needs to be heavily refactored, but that'll have to wait until the next release. :(

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
select (T)(object)m;
```

At runtime you've verified that `T` is a subtype of `MySpecialModel` but the compiler doesn't have access to this information at compile time.  It just sees an attempted conversion between 2 unrelated types: `T` and `MySpecialModel`.

To work around this you need to use `object` as a middle man.  The compiler understands how to convert `MySpecialModel` to `object` and to go from `object` to `T`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the generic type will always be a class, you can add a type constraint on your class:

```
public class Test<T> where T : class {}
```

Otherwise perform a double cast via object  as **smartcaveman** has suggested:

```
.Select(x => (T)(object)x);
```

Comment: read it again - I skimmed the first time too but he was actually asking how to cast the parameter `T` directly to `MySpecialModel`, which isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward fix is to cast to `object` first before the cast to `T`:

```
select (T)(object)m;
```

The problem is your check occurs at runtime, but the compiler doesn't know that `T` must be an instance of `MySpecialModel` within the `if` statement. Therefore it just sees you are trying to cast to some arbitrary type `T` from `MySpecialModel` which is not safe, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `as` keyword, put the `class` constraint on your generic parameter:

```
void MyMethod<T>(T item) where T : class
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do that as this class can also be used for `struct`'s.

Answer (score 0):

You might apply `Nullable<T>` constraint - that should enable the possibility to cast (at least using "as").